# Convert byte[] to file stream without writing to disk

Tags: c#, arrays, filestream

We are getting a input from a web service as a `byte[]` (which we process internally) and we need to upload to another web service which accepts only a file stream.

How can i to convert `byte[]` to a file stream **without writing to disk** in C#?

---

**Edit:** This is not duplicate. I am not asking how to convert `byte[]` to memory stream or file steam. I am asking how to convert `byte[]` to file stream **without writing to disk**. Please note that, I need to send the data as file steam to a third party web service, which I do not have access. This web service accepts only as file stream.

So far I have below code:

```
string fileWritePath = "c:\\temp\\test.docx";
//here fileContent is a byte[]
File.WriteAllBytes(fileWritePath, fileContent);
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileWritePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

I do not want to write the file to local disk and create file stream.

Comment: Create `MemoryStream` and "store" the byte[] array into it.

Comment: An external _web_ service accepts a _file_ stream? That doesn't seem to be possible. A file stream is on your disc and the web service is accessible through a network. These are two entirely different things.

Comment: I agree with @Sefe .Roughly speaking, a `FileStream`is a wrapper on an handle for a resource (a file on the disk usually). this handle has a meaning only locally, on the computer where you create the FileStream. When you pass this object to an external web server, the underlying handle will not have any meaning.

Comment: @css How can a web service only except FileStream? How do you access this service?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`MemoryStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using(var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray)){
   SendStreamToService(stream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are bound to a file stream, you have to use it. If you don't want to go through a physical hard drive you can install a *ram disc* on your system that maps parts of the memory to a virtual drive and use this drive to map your `FileStream` to.

Comment: see my comment above original post: even if you use a ram disk, I think the FileStream cannot work when you transfer it over a network

Comment: @GianPaolo: Maybe OP _says_ web service, but _means_ something else.

Answer (score 0):

This is enough. try it.

MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

Comment: Why duplicate an answer that already exist?